# Using the kendo ui web grid, how do i make a cell in my grid a link to my ActionResult in my controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In the example below I want to be able to click on the ProductName in the grid so that it takes me to my actionresult in my controller.  Any ideas?

```
<script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                            dataSource: {
                                      transport: {
                                          read: { url: '@Url.Action("GetCars", "Home")' }
                                pageSize: 20,
                                serverPaging: true,
                                serverSorting: true,
                                serverFiltering: true
                            },
                            toolbar: [ { name: "create", text: "Add a new car" }],
                            height: 550,
                            sortable: true,
                            pageable: true,
                            columns: [
                                { field: "ProductID", title: "Product ID", width: 100 },
                                { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
                                { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", width: 150 },
                                { field: "QuantityPerUnit", title: "Quantity Per Unit" }
                            ]
                        });
    </script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364098/pass-variable-from-kendo-datasource-to-template/22379829#22379829

Comment: Consider defining a template that either has an HTML anchor (`a`) or a `span` with an `onclick` event definition and put there the code to link to your ActionResult.